# Periodically getting locked out of back-end (admin panel)

Tags: magento-1.8, login, admin-panel, troubleshooting

Recently I've been having recurring issues login into the admin panel. It seems that if I do not login for 24 hours, the next time I go to login my credentials are not accepted.

**I know that I am typing in my username and password correctly.**

In order for me to successfully login it is necessary for me to clear the following:

```
*/var/session/*, */var/cache/* and */var/locks/*
```

What are the possible reasons for this to occur?

How can this be prevented and rectified without having to clear everything?

**UPDATE** 
I changed the Cookie Lifetime value from 24 hours to 12 hours with the same result. 
Multiple web-browsers will not work from multiple computers in different locations. In order to login I need to clear the *session* directory.

Notes: Magento 1.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like its related to cookie lifetime or/and the session lifetime. Try to lower the times for cookies and sessions. Also you might want to try with a different browser after those 24hs (i had some issues with Google Chrome and cookies).
Check 
System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Session Cookie management -> Cookie Lifetime

Edit: Session lifetime can be changed from System > Configuration > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (seconds)

Comment: interestingly enough my cookie lifetime was set to exactly 24 hours (86400) I'll lower it and see what happens. I'm pretty sure I tried different web browsers but will keep an eye on it.

Comment: Nope unrelated. I set the lifetime to 12 hours. Same issue this morning when I tried logging in. Will update the question thank you.

Comment: Question: did you removed all the cookies from the site previously created? If not, all of them will have the lifetime from the first creation process, which is 24hs.

Comment: yes, when I made the change, I cleared out everything, restarted all caching services and httpd. definitely fresh. I just changed the url for the admin panel and I'm getting much more stable results. I wonder if a previous developer is trying to hack and thats what is causing the issue?

Comment: You can check that in the access.log maybe.

Comment: It ended up being "Session Lifetime (seconds)" a developer had set it to one year. Add this to your answer and I will award it to you.

Comment: Added @sr_magento